Flutter generative AI sample API_KEY problem in Project IDX environment
I'm trying to practice Flutter generative AI sample in Project IDX environment. It needs Gemini API key. Readme says,
"
When running the app, include your API key using the --dart-define flag:
$ flutter run --dart-define=API_KEY=$GOOGLE_API_KEY
If you use VSCode, you can specify --dart-define variables in your launch.json file.
If you use Android Studio or IntelliJ you can use run / debug configurations (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration.html).
"
In Project IDX environment, the first method works. But it seems that the second method(launch.json) doesn't work. May I get advices?

You might need to rebuild your environment (or restart your workstation) after adding the API key to launch.json - you can do that by opening the Command Palette (CMD + Shift + P or Ctrl + Shift + P) and typing "Rebuild" to find the option "Project IDX: Rebuild environment"

did you have the chance to make it work? I'm also having problems even after rebuilding the environment
